# how can I add a text hover for data-table header in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, datatables-1.10, v-data-table

I would like to add a hover for headers of v-data-table

```js
<v-data-table 
   :headers= [{
      "text": "New Bizs Net Presence",
      "value": "new_biz_prom",
      "sortable": true,
      "align": "start"
   }]
   :items="this.rebuildReport" 
   v-if="ReportData.length != 0"
   class = "pa-2" 
   items-per-page=-1
></v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to add hover style. Make sure to add a custom class the data table, otherwise you will have to re-write a lot of Vuetify classes to get your style to override the default hover colour (`.theme--light.v-data-table .v-data-table-header th.sortable:hover`).

Adding a custom class to the table will make your style take precedence.

```
.custom-table th:hover {
  color: red;
}
```